# proving the following condition on a subset S of a finite group G is equivalent to that S isn't generating set of G

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

let $m \in \mathbb{N}$ show that there exists a finite group G with |G| > $m$
such that any subset S of G so that |S| < $log_2(|G|)$ is not a generating set of G.

---

i thought it could be proved using the definition $<S> = ${$s_1^{\epsilon_1}  ...s_n^{\epsilon_n} | s_1,...,s_n \in S , \epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_n \in ${-1,1}} and define a 1-1 and onto function from G to {-1,1}$^S$ .

am i wright? and can you find a better prove?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you've defined a 1-1 onto function from $G$ to $\{-1,1\}^S$. For example where does $s^2$ go for some $s\in S$ if $s$ has order greater than $2$?

I'll give a hopefully strong hint as an answer:

Your proof can be done by defining such a $G$ explicitly.

The condition is equivalent to $2^{|S|}<|G|$, so you need to think of a group for which any subset $S$ with $2^{|S|}<|G|$ generates a subgroup of order less than $G$.

Perhaps a subgroup of order $2^{|S|}$...